# how to change eye pupil color using opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, eye-detection

i am working on opencv in android. actually i am doing eye detection in opencv and want to change the color of eyes in real time. For Example: through front camera eye pupil is detcted and change the pupil color. i have problem in geting Hue channel. Kindly help

```
 Mat eyeball_HSV = new Mat();
   Mat dest = new Mat();  
   Mat eye = new Mat();

   eye = mRgba.submat(eye_template).clone();

   List<Mat> hsv_channel = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    //convert image to HSV 
     // Imgproc.cvtColor(eye, eyeball_RGB, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 3);
      Imgproc.cvtColor(eye, eyeball_HSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 0);
      //Core.inRange(eyeball_HSV, new Scalar(90, 50, 50), new Scalar(130, 255, 255), dest);
     // get HSV channel 
   //hsv_channel[0] is hue
   //hsv_channel[1] is saturation
   //hsv_channel[2] is visibility
      Core.split(eyeball_HSV, hsv_channel);

  try
  {
    hsv_channel.get(0).setTo(new Scalar(145));

    Log.v(TAG, "Got the Channel!");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   Log.v(TAG, "Didn't get any channel");
  }

  Imgproc.cvtColor(eyeball_HSV, dest, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGB);
  Imgproc.cvtColor(dest, eye, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
```

Comment: @Perroloco i am trying to get the Hue channel but there is no change in eye pupil color.

Comment: I see you update the hue to 145. It doesn't throw an exception right? when do you invalidate the view after that?

Comment: no exception. but i didnt get you, what do you mean by invalidate the view ??

Comment: where are you displaying the face / eyes

Comment: i have face/ eye matrix and i convert that matrix from mat to bitmap and display this in a view. my code is working well and also detect the eyeballs but i only want to get Hue channel

Comment: @SaadBilal did you got the answer ? if yes then please post it here.. i have the same issue.